# How to create pdf using asp.net c# without using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to export grid view data to pdf without using iTextSharp how I can create.
I can not create file like excel?

```
            DataSet dsReport = new DataSet();
            dsReport = (DataSet)ViewState["report"];    
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Detail.pdf");
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htm = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            Repeater repgetres = this.rptrabc;
            repgetres .DataSource = dsReport;
            repgetres .DataBind();
            repgetres .RenderControl(htm);                
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.End();
```

Comment: you can refer this, 
https://forums.asp.net/t/1899940.aspx?download+pdf+without+using+itextsharp+in+gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application will help

```
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

                    object missingvalue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                    object dummyfilename = "D://DummyFile.docx";
                    string pdfdata =  "D://HtmlFileData.html"; 
                    string pdffilename= "D://PDFFile.pdf";
                    object savechanges = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                    object ofalse = false;
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = word.Documents.Open(ref dummyfilename, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue);
                    doc.Words.Last.InsertFile(pdfdata, ref missingvalue, ref ofalse, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue);
                    doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(pdffilename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportOptimizeFor.wdExportOptimizeForOnScreen, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportRange.wdExportAllDocument, 1, 1, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportItem.wdExportDocumentWithMarkup, true, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdExportCreateBookmarks.wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, true, true, false, ref missingvalue);
                    doc.Close(ref savechanges,ref missingvalue,ref missingvalue);
                    word.Quit(ref savechanges, ref missingvalue, ref missingvalue);
```